# Python: Find specific link within HTML <a> tag

Tags: python, html

In Python I have a string containing the sourcecode of a website. Within this sourcecode I want to get the link within an tag, if the tag contains a specific substring.

The input e.g. looks like this:

```
AnyKindOfString <a href="http://www.link-to-get.com">SearchString</a> AndEvenMoreString
```

So what I want to tell Python is to search for `SearchString` in the all  tags within string and give me the first found `http://www.link-to-get.com` back.

This should only work, if `SearchString` is within the  tag - and it should also work, if "SearchString" is part (substring) of `http://www.link-to-get.com`.

I'm searching for an answer like more than 30 minutes know and the only thing I found for Python was simply to extract every (or only external or only internal) links from a string.

Anyone having an idea?

Thx in advance!

Comment: Have you looked at http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/ already?

Comment: I took a short look but actually did not find fitting functions for my case - you have a hint?

Answer (score 1):

using BeautifulSoup 3.2.1 with python 2.7

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

search_string = 'SearchString'

website_source = '<a href="http://www.link-to-get.com">SearchString</a> <a href="http://www.link-to-get.com">OtherString</a>\
                  <a href="http://www.link-to-getSearchString.com">otherString</a>'

soup = BeautifulSoup(website_source)

# this will return a list of lists that has the url's and the name for the link
anchors = [[row['href'], row.text] for row in soup.findAll('a') if row['href'].find(search_string) <> -1 or search_string in row.text]

# prints whole list
print anchors

#prints first list
print anchors[0]

# prints the url for the first list
print anchors[0][0]
```

The issue seems to be that I tested the above with BeautifulSoup 3.2.1 which only works in python 2.x and you are using python 3.4 hence the error.
If you install BeautifulSoup4 and try the below code it should work. also to note that BeautifulSoup4 which works in both 2.x and 3.x.

Please note that the below has not been tested.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

search_string = 'SearchString'

website_source = '<a href="http://www.link-to-get.com">SearchString</a> <a href="http://www.link-to-get.com">OtherString</a>\
                  <a href="http://www.link-to-getSearchString.com">otherString</a>'

soup = BeautifulSoup(website_source)

# this will return a list of lists that has the url's and the name for the link
anchors = [[row['href'], row.text] for row in soup.findAll('a') if row['href'].find(search_string) != -1 or search_string in row.text]

# prints whole list
print(anchors)

# prints first list
print(anchors[0])

# prints the url for the first list
print(anchors[0][0])
```

Comment: Hey Michael, thank you very much first. I think I've a problem with BeautifulSoup: I downloaded it and put it in my lib folder as "BeautifulSoup" - anyway, the "import BeautifulSoup" statement doesn't work: "Unsolved reference", PyCharm says. U got an idea?

Comment: it sounds like it may not be properly installed. have you tried installing it through pycharms package interpreter manager? are you using a virtualenv?

Comment: Successfully installed now via cmd :)

Comment: For line `anchors = [[row['href'], row.text] for row in soup.findAll('a') if row['href'].find(search_String) <> -1 or search_String in row.text]`, PyCharm simply says "invalid synthax" and `row['href'].find(search_String) <> -1` is underlined. You have an idea?

Comment: can you post the full error message as i can run it in my pycharm with only a warning saying that the line exceeds 125 characters

Comment: `C:\Python34\python.exe "C:/Users/Atilla/Google Drive/Internetrecherchen/Python Projects/SnippetTest_SearchStringLinkPairs/LinkFinder.py"
  File "C:/Users/Atilla/Google Drive/Internetrecherchen/Python Projects/SnippetTest_SearchStringLinkPairs/LinkFinder.py", line 11
    anchors = [[row['href'], row.text] for row in soup.findAll('a') if row['href'].find(search_string) <> -1 or search_string in row.text]
                                                                                                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Process finished with exit code 1`

Answer (score 0):

I've roughed up some code that should work, at least it works on the example string you gave.

```
myString = 'AnyKindOfString <a href="http://www.link-to-get.com">SearchString</a> AndEvenMoreString'

theLimit = len(myString)
searchStringLinkPairs = []
tempStr = myString[:]
i =0


while i < theLimit:
    startLoc = tempStr.find('<a')
    endLoc = tempStr.find("</a")
    print startLoc,"\t",endLoc
    subStr = tempStr[startLoc:endLoc]
    startLink = subStr.find("\"")
    subTwo = subStr[startLink+1:]
    endLink = subTwo.find("\"")
    myLink = subStr[startLink+1:startLink+1+endLink]

    searchStringStart = subStr.find(">")
    searchString = subStr[searchStringStart+1:endLoc]

    if myLink != "" and searchString != "":
        searchStringLinkPairs.append([myLink, searchString])
    tempStr = tempStr[endLoc+1:]
    i = endLoc
    if startLoc == -1 or endLoc == -1:
        i = 10 * theLimit

print searchStringLinkPairs
```

Comment: Thanks russOnXMaps, the code works - but I need to define, which string to search for and I need to do it for the entire sourcecode of a website which can contain multiple links of course. With your code and redefining myString with `'AnyKindOfString <a href="http://www.link-to-get.com">SearchString</a>AndEvenMoreString and <a href="http://www.beispielseite.com">SearchString2</a> other Stuff'` this leads to an infinite loop.... O.o

Comment: Yup, 

Change 
    tempStr = tempStr[endLoc:]
to
    tempStr = tempStr[endLoc+1:]

Answer (score 0):

Can be done with the help of `pyquery`(http://pythonhosted.org/pyquery/index.html) + `lxml`(http://lxml.de/tutorial.html) as follows

```
from pyquery import PyQuery as pq
from lxml import etree

pq_obj = pq(etree.fromstring('<body><p>AnyKindOfString <a href="http://www.link-to-get.com">SearchString</a> AndEvenMoreString</p><p>this is another string goes here</p><a> other</a></body>'))
search_string = 'SearchString'

links = pq_obj('a')
for link in links:
    if search_string in link.text:
        attrib = link.attrib
        print attrib.get('href')

# output
# http://www.link-to-get.com
```